# How do I write a sed one-liner to add a character after every third character?

Tags: text-processing, sed

So, I have a string that looks like this:

```
AUGGCCAUGGCGCCCAGAACUGAGAUCAAUAGUACCCGUAUUAACGGGUGA
```

And I want to split the string into 3-character chunks delimited by a '+' sign.

```
AUG+GCC+AUG+GCG+CCC+AGA+ACU+GAG+AUC+AAU+AGU+ACC+CGU+AUU+AAC+GGG+UGA
```

And I want to do that with my good friend `sed`.

I tried

```
cat codons | sed -r 's/([A-Z]\{3\})/\1\+/g'
```

...with no success.

What `sed` command can I use?

Comment: Aren't this somehow connected to [Rosalind](http://rosalind.info)? Just curious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you don't want a trailing `+`, you could do:

```
fold -w3 | paste -sd+ -
```

That is, <kbd>fold</kbd> the lines on <kbd>3</kbd> character <kbd>w</kbd>idth, and <kbd>paste</kbd> those 3 character lines with them<kbd>s</kbd>elves with <kbd>+</kbd> as the <kbd>d</kbd>elimiter which in effect is like changing every newline character but the last one into a `+`. If the input had more than one line, you'll end up with those lines joined with a `+` which may or may not be what you want.

If you do need it to be `sed`, you can remove the trailing `+` after:

```
sed 's/.../&+/g;s/+$//'
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a short explanation of how that works?

Comment: @N.N. It works because `+$` matches a plus symbol immediately before the end of a line.

Comment: `fold -w3` breaks the string into 3 character lines. `paste -sd+ -` turns the newlines into `+`.

Answer (score 12):

```
sed 's/.../&+/g'
```

to get your way working you don't need to escape `{}` symbols:

```
sed -r 's/([A-Z]{3})/\1+/g'
```

Comment: who knew! i was so close yet so far... thanks...

Comment: Both add a trailing '+'. Is this intended?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/...\B/&+/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If sed is not a must using Ruby might be an alternative. The Ruby interpreter, `ruby`,  can be used like sed and awk by running it with the `-n` option which makes it iterate over its input. The interpreter can then be feed with a Ruby one-liner by adding it as an argument to the `-e` option (which tells the interpreter to interpret the argument of `-e` rather than looking for a script in a file).

For this particular problem you can use the following one-liner (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184271/789593):

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/.{3}|.+/).join("+")'
```

In plain language it

- matches any 3 characters or at least one character, `scan(/.{3}|.+/)`, in the input string, `$_` (in this case the input is expected to come from standard in) and puts each match in an array,
- joins the array into a string with a '+' connecting each element, `join("+")`,
- and prints it terminated by a newline `puts`.

For example

```
echo "AUGGCCAUGGCGCCCAGAACUGAGAUCAAUAGUACCCGUAUUAACGGGUG" | ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/.{3}|.+/).join("+")'
AUG+GCC+AUG+GCG+CCC+AGA+ACU+GAG+AUC+AAU+AGU+ACC+CGU+AUU+AAC+GGG+UG
```

Note that it does not add any trailing '+'.