# How to add a specific character after every one character?

Tags: text-processing

I have a number -> 12345

I want output in below format

```
1+2+3+4+5
```

---

```
echo `cat fl.txt | paste -s -d ''`
```

gives only `12345`.

But when I add this + at the below command it gives same `12345`.

```
echo `cat fl.txt | paste -s -d '' | tr -s '' '+'`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a sed one-liner to add a character after every third character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59144/how-do-i-write-a-sed-one-liner-to-add-a-character-after-every-third-character)

Comment: So actually you don't want  a specific character after every one character, but only in between two characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to insert space between individual digits in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302407/how-to-insert-space-between-individual-digits-in-a-file)

Answer (score 10):

With GNU sed, you can also do:

```
sed 's/./+&/2g'
```

Answer (score 6):

It's easier to split a string into characters:

```
fold -w1 file | paste -sd+ -
```

Some versions of the `fold` command do not have the `-c` option but have the `-w` option. In this case, they will be interchangeable.
or:

```
grep -o '.' file | paste -sd+ -
```

Perhaps with one command:

```
awk -v OFS='+' -F '' '{$1=$1; print}' file
```

And:

```
sed 's/\B/+/g' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
$ number=12345
$ printf '%s\n' ${(j[+])${(s[])number}}
1+2+3+4+5
```

`s[]` parameter expansion flag to split `$number` into its character components. `j[+]` to join them back with `+`.

With `bash`:

```
$ number=12345
$ shopt -s extglob
$ tmp=${number//@()/+}
$ printf '%s\n' "${tmp#+}"
1+2+3+4+5
```

`${number//@()/+}` replaces all the occurrences of *nothing* with `+`. For some reason `${number///+}` doesn't seem to work in `bash` (it works in `zsh` though).

Answer (score 2):

If you're loooking for shell-only, this is bash:

```bsh
input=1245
output=""
while IFS= read -r -n1 char; do output+="${char}+"; done < <(printf %s "$input")
output=${output%+}
echo "$output"         # => 1+2+4+5
```

The odd looking `< <(printf %s "$input")` is a process substitution that redirects the input, with no trailing newline, into the while-read loop.

Or sed

```bsh
output=$( sed 's/./&+/g; s/+$//' <<<"$input")
```

Comment: Probably not an issue with the OP's input (meant to be a number), but note that the `read` approach assumes `$input` contains no character of `$IFS` nor newlines.

Answer (score 2):

just some other possibilities using perl instead of awk or sed:

```bsh
echo 12345 | perl -lpe '$_ = join "+", split //;'
```

or (if the number is saved in `fl.txt`)

```bsh
# echo 12345 > fl.txt
perl -lpe '$_ = join "+", split //;' fl.txt
```

the `-l` param just avoids the line ending being included (when joining with "+"). otherwise you'd have `1+2+3+4+5+` as result.

alternatively you can use the method, similar as the one mentioned for sed already:

```bsh
perl -pe 's/.\K/+/g; s/\+$//;' fl.txt
```

or

```bsh
perl -pe 's/.\K(?!$)/+/g;' fl.txt
```

or

```bsh
perl -pe 's/\B/+/g;' fl.txt
```

output in all cases:

```
1+2+3+4+5
```

Answer (score 0):

### Split/Join Characters with Ruby

There are lots of ways to do this. On way is to use Ruby to split your string into characters, and then join them back together with the `+` symbol. For example, at the shell prompt:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ARGV.first.chars.join "+"' 12345
1+2+3+4+5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ echo 12345 | raku -ne 'put .comb.join("+");'
1+2+3+4+5

#OR

~$ echo 12345 | raku -pe '.=comb; .=join("+");'
1+2+3+4+5
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family of programming languages. The code above uses Raku's new `comb` routine, which sifts through the input text to break *around* (and select out) a desired sequence, converse to the action of the `split` operator. Without any parameters, `comb()` breaks before/after each character. Here, because the target sequence is digits, `comb(/ \d /)` might prove useful:

```perl
% echo abcd12345efgh | raku -ne 'put .comb(/ \d /).join("+");'
1+2+3+4+5

#OR

% echo abcd12345efgh | raku -pe '.=comb(/ \d /); .=join("+");'
1+2+3+4+5
```

This isn't to say that other options aren't available. Below are solutions in a similar vein to the excellent Perl solutions posted by @uvularer_frikativ:

```perl
~$ echo 12345 | raku -pe '$_ = join "+", .split: "", :skip-empty;'
1+2+3+4+5

#OR

~$ echo 12345 > 12345.txt
~$ raku -pe '$_ = join "+", .split: "", :skip-empty;'  12345.txt
1+2+3+4+5
```

Some more Raku options:

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ )> . /+/;  s/^\+//;' 12345.txt
1+2+3+4+5

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g/<!after ^> )> . /+/;' 12345.txt
1+2+3+4+5

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g/ <?after . >  <!before $ > /+/;' 12345.txt
1+2+3+4+5

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g/<ww>/+/;' 12345.txt
1+2+3+4+5
```

http://raku.org